# Is taro (satoimo) bark edible after grilling?

Tags: food-safety

I'm aware that raw taro is toxic and needs to be properly cooked.  However, I'm seeing some conflicting information online about eating taro bark.  An [article on WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Taro_Root) states,

> The hairy outer layer is always removed with caution since skin irritation can arise caused by the juices secreted by the taro root.

However, a [Japanese recipe](http://recipe.igamono.jp/?eid=1175468) for grilling taro clearly keeps the skin on.  Google translates a part of the recipe as:

> Wash the root vegetables thoroughly with scrubbing etc. (Picture 1), cut into a 1 cm wide stripe **with the skin**.

Photos accompanying the Japanese recipe clearly show the taro with the skin on, [here](http://img-cdn.jg.jugem.jp/041/1528719/20101203_1543837.jpg) and [here](http://img-cdn.jg.jugem.jp/041/1528719/20101203_1543839.jpg).

Perhaps I've answered my own question, but can anyone confirm that the bark is edible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my understanding that cooking the taro (including the skin) reduces the toxins to an acceptable level. I think the aversion to eating the skin has more to do with texture than anything else.

Boiling is also more effective at removing the calcium oxalate than baking.

If the recipe is from a reliable source, I'd go for it.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the advice on boiling the taro.